# How read ELF header in C?

Tags: c, elf

How to open the file and copy the info into another file. I just need to copy the magic number and version. 
void read_header(FILE *file, File *file2);

Comment: You could consider using the ELF library — `libelf`.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to achieve? Copying all the info to another file is done using `fread` and `fwrite` - just remember to open in binary mode. ELF files are no different from other binary files.

Comment: You're not allowed to change the meaning of your question. If you have a new question you should post it as new question, but be sure to check first that it hasn't already been asked.

Answer (score 17):

Depending on the platform, a header file already defining this structure might be available. For instance you can try to include `elf.h` if you're running linux:

```
#include <elf.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#if defined(__LP64__)
#define ElfW(type) Elf64_ ## type
#else
#define ElfW(type) Elf32_ ## type
#endif

void read_elf_header(const char* elfFile) {
  // Either Elf64_Ehdr or Elf32_Ehdr depending on architecture.
  ElfW(Ehdr) header;

  FILE* file = fopen(elfFile, "rb");
  if(file) {
    // read the header
    fread(&header, sizeof(header), 1, file);

    // check so its really an elf file
    if (memcmp(header.e_ident, ELFMAG, SELFMAG) == 0) {
       // this is a valid elf file
    }

    // finally close the file
    fclose(file);
  }
}
```

If you system does not already include the `elf.h` you can check how the elf header is structured [here.](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf)
Then you can create a struct to hold your data and simply read it like this:

```
typedef struct {
  uint8     e_ident[16];         /* Magic number and other info */
  uint16    e_type;              /* Object file type */
  uint16    e_machine;           /* Architecture */
  uint32    e_version;           /* Object file version */
  uint64    e_entry;             /* Entry point virtual address */
  uint64    e_phoff;             /* Program header table file offset */
  uint64    e_shoff;             /* Section header table file offset */
  uint32    e_flags;             /* Processor-specific flags */
  uint16    e_ehsize;            /* ELF header size in bytes */
  uint16    e_phentsize;         /* Program header table entry size */
  uint16    e_phnum;             /* Program header table entry count */
  uint16    e_shentsize;         /* Section header table entry size */
  uint16    e_shnum;             /* Section header table entry count */
  uint16    e_shstrndx;          /* Section header string table index */
} Elf64Hdr;

void read_elf_header(const char* elfFile, const char* outputFile) {
  struct Elf64Hdr header;

  FILE* file = fopen(elfFile, "rb");
  if(file) {
    // read the header
    fread(&header, 1, sizeof(header), file);

    // check so its really an elf file
    if(header.e_type == 0x7f &&
       header.e_ident[1] == 'E' &&
       header.e_ident[2] == 'L' &&
       header.e_ident[3] == 'F') {

       // write the header to the output file
       FILE* fout = fopen(outputFile, "wb");
       if(fout) {
         fwrite(&header, 1, sizeof(header), fout);
         fclose(fout);
       }
     }

    // finally close the file
    fclose(file);
  }
}
```

Comment: Note: your platform *may* define this structure in a header file already, so you don't need to copy it. But I don't remember what it's called or which header.

Comment: can better use `ElfW(Ehdr)` instead of `Elf64_Ehdr` or `Elf32_Ehdr`

Answer (score 3):

1. Include elf.h
2. Open and Stat elf file
3. Map file
4. Typecast map address to Elf64_Ehdr and read

Comment: You don't need to open the file to call `stat` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Open your elf file using `fopen()`

```
FILE *fp  = fopen("youe_elf.bin","rb");
```

Now using `fread()` Read block of data from file. and map with the [format of ELF file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) and get header bytes and write them in new file again using `fopen()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want bare-metal parsing, follow Cyclone's proposition or, e.g. have a look at other people doing so, like Qt in http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/plugin/qelfparser_p.cpp .

Yet, there are a couple of libraries with higher-level APIs. Take https://wiki.freebsd.org/LibElf as a starting point.